# forEach and object constructors

Tags: javascript, object

I have the following code that takes an array of objects and creates new objects using a constructor.

To avoid creating instances one by one I have tried to create them using the forEach method on the array.

The problem I have is that when I try to log the result the objects created by the constructor are returned as 'undefined'.

I expect this is because the objects are scoped inside of the forEach callback and not accessible outside of this.

Is there a way that I can access the objects I've created ?

If not can anyone please suggest to me if there is a better way way that I could structure my code to achieve the same outcome ?

```
// Array of 'Person' objects

let persons = [
    {
        name: "A",
        number: "000-1111-1111",
        location: "London"
    },
    {
        name: "B",
        number: "000-2222-2222",
        location: "Leeds"
    },
    {
        name: "C",
        number: "000-333-3333",
        location: "London"
    }
];


// Persons constructor

Person = function(name, number) {
    this.name = name;
    this.number = number;
};


// For each obj in array create a new constructor

persons.forEach(item => {
    if (item.location === "London") {
        let person = item.name;
        person = new Person(item.name, item.number);
        console.log(person);
    }
});


// Console log out new object for 'A'

console.log( Person )
console.log( A );
```

Comment: Use `.map()` instead of `.forEach()`, return each constructed Person, and you'll end up with a new array. *edit* actually use `.filter()` to get just the London people and then use `.map()`

Comment: persons is already an array of objects or persons :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, the issue that you have is that you want to have a global variable which name is a dynamic string. In this case, assuming that you want the access in the global scope, you can use the window object :

```
let persons = [
    {
        name: "A",
        number: "000-1111-1111",
        location: "London"
    },
    {
        name: "B",
        number: "000-2222-2222",
        location: "Leeds"
    },
    {
        name: "C",
        number: "000-333-3333",
        location: "London"
    }
];


// Persons constructor

Person = function(name, number) {
    this.name = name;
    this.number = number;
};


// For each obj in array create a new constructor

persons.forEach(item => {
    if (item.location === "London") {
        window[item.name] = new Person(item.name, item.number);
    }
});


// Console log out new object for 'A'

console.log( Person )
console.log( A );
```

Comment: Thanks Pierre! You are correct and this what I was trying to achieve - making the newly created person object(s) available outside of the forEach (and globally). Thanks everyone else for the answers too!

Answer (score 2):

If what you want is a *new* array containing constructed `Person` objects, you can use `.map()`. You'll also want to use `.filter()` in order to limit the results to the proper elements based on your "London" condition:

```
let people = persons.filter(item => item.location === "London")
    .map(item => new Person(item.name, item.number));
```

Note that you really should declare that `Person` variable with `let` or `var` or `const`; as written your code creates an implicit global variable.